# sub() function replaces all matches

Tags: r, match

it's me again,

I have a problem with the sub()-function in R:
The documentation says: "sub and gsub perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively."

I have a code, where I want to replace only one item with another (conditionally, say that if an item appears I want it to be two times in a vector - but that's not necessary information here).

However, if I perform the sub-function, it replaces everything. Here some code to demonstrate what's happening:

```
a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a")
> sub("a", "f", a)
[1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "f" "b" "c" "d" "f" "f"
> gsub("a", "f", a)
[1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "f" "b" "c" "d" "f" "f"
```

As you can see, in my case sub and gsub perform the same action, however I want the result to be the following:

```
a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a")
> sub("a", "f", a)
[1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "a"
```

I don't understand why that is happening, to me it does not seem in line with the documentation. Can anybody explain to me the reason or a workaround?

Comment: That only works within one string, you have a vector of string, so each element is treated separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` to find the first hit and use the returned index to replace the string.

```
a[match("a", a)]  <- "f"
a
# [1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "a"
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex in `sub` treats every vector differently. Maybe the below example might help you understand the difference in them.

```
a = c("aaaa", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a")
sub("a", "f", a)
#[1] "faaa" "b"    "c"    "d"    "f"    "b"    "c"    "d"    "f"    "f" 

gsub("a", "f", a)
#[1] "ffff" "b"    "c"    "d"    "f"    "b"    "c"    "d"    "f"    "f"
```

so with `sub` only the first `"a"` is turned to `"f"` whereas with `gsub` all the `"a"`s are turned to `"f"`. Also this looks like an exact match and not partial match, so no need to use regex here.

You can compare `a` with `"a"` and replace the first occurrence with `"f"`.

```
a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a")
a[which.max(a == "a")] <- "f"
a
#[1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "a"
```

Comment: That was an indeed really helpful explanation why that occurs! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only one character per element, and if you can afford to merge and split the vectors, you can do

```
> unlist(strsplit(sub("a","f",paste0(a,collapse="")),""))
 [1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grepl` here to find all indices in your input vector which contain `"a"`.  Then, selectively replace only the first matching index.

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a")
a[min(which(grepl("a", a) == TRUE))] <- "f"
a

[1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "a"
```

Note that `sub()` will in fact the first match in the pattern, but *for each input*.  The `sub()` function is vectorized, and when you pass a vector to it, instead of a single value, it will replace the first match in *each* value of the vector, not only in the first element.

Answer (score 0):

As @user2974951 points out in his comment, `sub(pat, repl, x)` is vectorised, meaning it will replace the first instance of `pat` with `repl` in *every* element of `x`.

If you must use `sub` you could concatenate the entries, replace `pat` with `repl`, and then split the string again on every character.

```
unlist(strsplit(sub("a", "f", paste0(a, collapse = "")), ""))
#[1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "a"
```